# How to use different Junit TestRunner in Eclipse and Ant?

Tags: java, ant, junit, jbehave, test-runner

I have a couple of JBehave tests that I want to run from Eclipse and Ant. In Eclipse I want to see a tree of all the different stories, scenarios and steps that are performed in the graphical output, so I added a custom runner to the tests that does this:

```
@RunWith(de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public class MyStoryTest extends org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories
{
    // ...
}
```

But on contrary when running the tests with Ant and in the Continuous Integration server I want to see only every whole story as a single item in the output. This is usually achieved without any annotation:

```
public class MyStoryTest extends JUnitStories
{
    // ...
}
```

So how can I tell Ant (junit Ant task) to use a different runner than Eclipse?
To make things more complicated: At the moment I use a test suite in Eclipse (not in Ant) to run the tests:

```
@RunWith(org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite.class)
@org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClassnameFilters("foo.mypackage.tests.*")
public class MyStoriesTestSuite
{
    // Nothing more to say ;)
}
```

Any Ideas?

Cheers, Tilmann

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some hack a few weeks ago, that can fit your needs. I realized, that the java command, which is executed by Eclipse in case of a unit test run contains always a package in its name. So if this gives back true, probably you are running your test under Eclipse:

```
System.getProperty( "sun.java.command" ).contains( "org.eclipse.jdt" )
```

I know, its not 100 percent solution, but **usually works, and its better than nothing**.

I created and tested a Runner+Annotation pair for you:

**Annotation**:

```
package org.junit.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target( ElementType.TYPE )
public @interface RunWithInEnvironment {
    Class<? extends Runner> eclipse();
    Class<? extends Runner> defaultRunner() default JUnit4.class;
}
```

By default it uses JUnit4 as defaultrunner, which is really the default for JUnit4.

**The Runner**, which uses the information of the annotation:

```
package org.junit.runners;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.annotation.RunWithInEnvironment;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;

public class EnvironmentDependentRunner extends Runner {
    protected Class<?> testClass;
    protected Runner delegate;

    public EnvironmentDependentRunner(Class<?> testClass) {
        super();
        this.testClass = testClass;
        RunWithInEnvironment annotation = findAnnotationInClassHierarchy(testClass);
        assertNotNull( EnvironmentDependentRunner.class.getSimpleName() + " can be used only with test classes, that are annotated with " + RunWithInEnvironment.class.getSimpleName() + " annotation somewhere in their class hierarchy!", annotation );
        Class<? extends Runner> delegateClass = null;
        if ( System.getProperty( "sun.java.command" ).contains( "org.eclipse.jdt" ) && annotation.eclipse() != null ) {
            delegateClass = annotation.eclipse();
        }
        else {
            delegateClass = annotation.defaultRunner();
        }
        try {
            Constructor<? extends Runner> constructor = delegateClass.getConstructor( Class.class );
            delegate = constructor.newInstance(testClass);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            fail( delegateClass.getName() + " must contain a public constructor with a " + Class.class.getName() + " argument.");
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SecurityException during instantiation of " + delegateClass.getName() );
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while creating " + delegateClass.getName() );
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while creating " + delegateClass.getName() );
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while creating " + delegateClass.getName() );
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while creating " + delegateClass.getName() );
        }
    }

    private RunWithInEnvironment findAnnotationInClassHierarchy(Class<?> testClass) {
        RunWithInEnvironment annotation = testClass.getAnnotation(RunWithInEnvironment.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            return annotation;
        }

        Class<?> superClass = testClass.getSuperclass();
        if (superClass != null) {
            return findAnnotationInClassHierarchy(superClass);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return delegate.getDescription();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier arg0) {
        delegate.run(arg0);
    }
}
```

And an **usage example**:

```
@RunWithInEnvironment( eclipse=JUnit4.class, defaultRunner=Parameterized.class)
@RunWith( EnvironmentDependentRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
...
}
```

So this test will run with JUnit4 runner in Eclipse,  with Parameterized outside Eclipse.

Comment: If you don't like the environment entry, you can also get the trace of the thread, and look up some eclipse specific classes in it.

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you a lot! And it works almost perfekt. The only thing I changed was to look up the annotation along the super class hierarchy if not found on a class.

Comment: Then please make an edit of my post, and then the others can have this change as well.